# Kivy - automatically start a method from popup

Tags: python, methods, popup, kivy, background-process

**PROBLEM**

I am using Python3 and Kivy2. Regardless I would like a popup to automatically start a time consuming method in the background

**DESCRIPTION**
In the script call for the popup when a condition is met.

```
if  self.header == "loadbag":
    messageTitle = "machine status"
    messageLabel = "work in progress"
    self.popup(messageTitle, messageLabel)
```

The popup method structure is:

```
def popup(self, boxTitle, boxLabel):    # popup for showing the activity
    self.MessageButtonCancel = "ANNULLA"
    self.MessageBoxTitle = boxTitle
    self.MessageBoxLabel = boxLabel
    self.popup = ActivityBox(self)
    self.popup.open()
```

The kv language part in the Builder.load_string for the ActivityBox is:

```
<ActivityBox>:
    size_hint: 1, .7
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            # both buttons are not necessary
            # the popup just shows a message
            # Button:
                # font_size: 50
                # background_color: 0,204,0,1
                # text: app.MessageButtonConfirm  # "CONFIRM"
                # on_press:
                    # self.disabled = True
                    # self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                    # app.do()
            # Button:
                # font_size: 50
                # background_color: 204,0,0,1
                # text: app.MessageButtonCancel  # "CANCEL"
                # on_press:
                    # self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    # app.cancel()
                    # root.dismiss()
```

As you can see, the buttons in the ActivityBox are disabled as I only want the label to appear. Below are some similar questions I have checked without finding a solution.

1. [Displaying something in kivy while a process is running background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238034/displaying-something-in-kivy-while-a-process-is-running-background)
2. [Kivy: how to display a widget while waiting for another one to be displayed (both called from a same event)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811241/kivy-how-to-display-a-widget-while-waiting-for-another-one-to-be-displayed-bot)
3. [Kivy popup running in separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936619/kivy-popup-running-in-separate-thread)
4. [Pop up Kivy displaying while a process is running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924125/pop-up-kivy-displaying-while-a-process-is-running-in-background)
5. [Open kivy popup before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732400/open-kivy-popup-before-continuing)

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to start a method automatically from within the ActivityBox, without binding it to the buttons?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to insert the method call in the def popup(self, boxTitle, boxLabel): but the popup appeared only after the method terminated.

```
def popup(self, boxTitle, boxLabel):    # popup for showing the activity
    self.MessageBoxTitle = boxTitle
    self.MessageBoxLabel = boxLabel
    self.popup = ActivityBox(self)
    self.time_consuming_method() # here goes the method to run
    self.popup.open()
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried with threading without success. The popup and the method each in a separate thread. The popup appeared only after the method terminated.

```
    def popup(self, boxTitle, boxLabel):    # popup for showing the activity
        self.MessageBoxTitle = boxTitle
        self.MessageBoxLabel = boxLabel
        self.popup = ActivityBox(self)
        self.popup.open()
    
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = popup, args = (boxTitle, boxLabel))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = time_consuming_method)
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `join()` method of a `Thread` causes a wait until that `Thread` has completed, which is almost equivalent to not using `threading`.

Try eliminating thread `t1`, and just call `popup` without using a new thread for that. Then start thread `t2`, but eliminate the `t2.join()` call.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

The answer proposed @John Anderson was helpful. The join method causes an undesired wait.

First I tried to run the `def popup` method as the lead and the `time_consuming_method` as a thread. This approach did not solved the problem.

**NOT WORKING CODE**

```
    def popup(self, boxTitle, boxLabel):    # popup for showing the activity
        self.MessageBoxTitle = boxTitle
        self.MessageBoxLabel = boxLabel
        self.popup = ActivityBox(self)
        self.popup.open()
    
    self.popup(boxTitle, boxLabel)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = time_consuming_method)
    t2.start()
```

Then I tried running `self.popup.open()` method as the lead and the the `time_consuming_method` as a thread from inside the `def popup` method. This solution worked out fine, the popup appears when the method starts.

**WORKING CODE**

```
    def popup(self, boxTitle, boxLabel):    # popup for showing the activity
        self.MessageBoxTitle = boxTitle
        self.MessageBoxLabel = boxLabel
        self.popup = ActivityBox(self)
        self.popup.open()                   # call the popup    
        t2 = threading.Thread(target = time_consuming_method)    # define the thread
        t2.start()    # start the thread
```